# Getting NullPointerException persistently on line with no code on it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Essentially I'm trying to load an resize an image to put it on a JButton. This was working earlier today but when I brought my drive home to work on it and ran the program I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I'm quite new to Java so forgive me if I'm wrong but normally this essentially means I'm calling something that doesn't exist. Regardless of this it states the error is on line 179, even if I move the code up or down a few lines. Even when there is no code on this line I get the error. I've included the code near the error, and included the full error message on the bottom.

Thanks!

```
Image play = null;
try {
    play = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/play.png"));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("true");

Image pause = null;
try {
    pause = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/pause.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// The line it says the error is on.
ImageIcon playIcon = new ImageIcon(play.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
ImageIcon pauseIcon = new ImageIcon(pause.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

btnPause.setIcon(playIcon);
btnPause.setSelectedIcon(pauseIcon);
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.<init>(Main.java:179)
at Main$1.run(Main.java:55)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you recompile after you edited the code?

Comment: Sorry for my own stupidity here. But when you say recompile you mean press the run button correct? If so yes I have. The only changes I made was to shorten:

play = play.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
ImageIcon playIcon = new ImageIcon(play);

into 

     ImageIcon playIcon = new ImageIcon(play.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

Comment: I don't know what environment you're using for development or whether it compiles automatically, but "running" is the thing that you do *after* compiling.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has an issue with the way you are using `try..catch` blocks and the handling of your exceptions. Taking the relevant code from your example:

```
try {
    play = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/play.png"));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
ImageIcon playIcon = new ImageIcon(play.getScaledInstance(25, 25, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

If the second line (that reads the image and assigns it to `play`) fails, the exception is thrown, caught and printed out. And then *you continue on, even though `play` will not have been assigned*. So when you call `play.getScaledInstance()` you will get a `NullPointerException` because `play` is `null`.

What you need to do instead, is stop processing and return some indication of the failure. You cannot continue.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I don't think that play = ImageIO etc etc should ever fail but I guess thats probably needed for other cases. How can I modify the try/catch blocks to remove the error? Is it something as simple as added System.exit(0); into the catch block?

Comment: Also thanks for the help, but why is eclipse saying the error is on a completely different line?

Comment: Well if it can never fail, why put it in a try/catch block :)   Was the exception printed, ie. did it actually fail? If not, there may be another cause somewhere. Yes, you can use `System.exit(0)` if you like.

Comment: I'm confused. Is line 179 the line the comment in your code refers to?